# Convergence of Alternating Series Involving Cosine Term and Square Root

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

I am working on a series and attempting to determine its conditional convergence using the alternating series test.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2\pi n\right)}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

I think it satisfies the conditions for the alternating series test: it alternates sign due to the cosine term, and the absolute values of the terms appear to be decreasing as n increases. However, the solution manual for my textbook suggests that the series is diverging. Am I correct in using the alternating series test?

Comment: Check the values of the cosine again: are you sure they alternate?

Comment: ... indeed $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2\pi n\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ : no alternate signs... Isn't it $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n\right)$ ?